# Undefined offset: 3 , 4 5 from explode in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, explode

I have php source from controller in codeigniter

```
      date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Jakarta');
      $now_j=date("H");
      $now_m=date("i");
      $now_d=date("s");

      $query=$this->db->get('tanggal')->row();
      $tgl= explode(" :-", $query->tanggal);
      $dnow=($now_j*3600)+($now_m*60)+($now_d);
      $dtanggal=($tgl['3']*3600)+($tgl['4']*60)+$tgl['5'];
      $hasil = $tanggal-$dnow;

      echo $hasil;
```

Why i get Undenfined offset in row $dtanggal bla bla,,, Can you help me

Comment: Please post your exact error message.

Comment: `print_r($tgl);`and check how many indexes it has?

Comment: @ak-sonu "2015-07-27 22:00:001,,

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined offset: 3
Filename: parti/hparti.php
Line Number: 11

Comment: so you have an array with 3 elements: `0,1,2`. there is no `3` or `4`, and your error message is exactly correct.

Comment: ` $tgl= explode(" :-", $query->tanggal);` this will not going to explode at all,because it will not get `:-`anywhere.

Comment: solved,,, i want get just hours, minutes, second,,, so i using 2 explode,,, first explode (" ") space,,, second explode (":").... thanks all :D